# javascript - Mouse Click on parent element , but prevent it's child element to fire event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

How to define on child element, not to trigger an event,
like on `.mouseclick = 'no-event'` or : `.mousedown = 'no-event'`
with natural Javascript command?

So, it's parent will get the the first event before bubbling-up,
the parent element event will get e. `target = e.currentTarget`

I need to do it on some specific child elements, and some not.

On parent element the 'capture', does not give the correct behaviour
as mentioned above.

All other solutions I follow on the web, are giving many 'tricky' solutions
that don't work correctly.

Comment: XAML frameworks like WPF and WinUI have a `PreviewMouseXXX` event which bubbles DOWN from the parent to the children and fires before the corresponding `MouseXXX` event. This gives the parent a chance to intercept the event before it gets to the child, who might stop bubbling. I was looking for a Javascript equivalent but it seems there is none.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById('parent');
var childEl = document.getElementById('child');

parentEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

}, true)
childEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

}, true)

If you pass the true on eventListener it stops the event from bubbling.
```

Comment: I mentioned above the capture=true is not good, because it prevent all childs, I want to define it on specific child Elements, the capture on child element is useless

Answer (score 0):

You could give the children a custom class which determines it should be clickable or not.
Inside the callback function for it's parent container check which class the target is using and act accordingly.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className == "clickable") {
    console.log("I should do something!");
  } else {
    console.log("I should NOT do something!");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="clickable">
    this is clickable
  </div>
  <div>
    this is not clickable
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution, not preventing click event on child element, the parent element is bubbled from child and the e.target <> e.currentTarget, this cause not getting correct event positioning values from parent element, as mentioned above, need direct solution and not if's and else...